# How can I add an image overlaying an img tag?

Tags: html, css, image, tags, background-image

Is there a way in CSS to add an image background over the image on an img tag?

I have a tag on my site similar to

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
```

and my CSS is as follows:

```
.field img {width: 354px; min-width: 354px; height: 200px; object-fit: cover;}
```

I can't conveniently edit the HTML, so I'm hoping to find a CSS solution. Is there something I can add to this CSS to overlay a background image *over* the image? I'm planning to add something which looks like a transparent "play" button over images which link to videos.

There are many ideas online which answer this question, but I haven't seen one that doesn't require an extra div.

Comment: a play button ? where does it stand in your HTML ?

Comment: pseudo-elements/children are not allowed on `img`, `br`, `hr`, `input` and other [void elements](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/syntax.html#void-element)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I am a little too late to answer. But I found the best way to do this using the css propery mix-blend-mode.

```css
body {
  font-family: Calibri
}

img {
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75));
  width: 400px;
  height: 260px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px gray;
}

.card img.overlay {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}

.card>.bottom-text {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h3>Using the mix-blend-mode property</h3>

  <h4>With mix-blend-mode overlay:</h4>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="overlay" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/10/15/16/white-horse-3010129_960_720.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="400" height="260">
    <span class="bottom-text">
    IN RIDING A HORSE<br>
    WE BORROW FREEDOM
  </span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <h4>Original image without overlay:</h4>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/10/15/16/white-horse-3010129_960_720.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="400" height="260">
    <span class="bottom-text">
    IN RIDING A HORSE<br>
    WE BORROW FREEDOM
  </span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, here comes a funny answer or at least useless style:

- image sized to zero and applied too to background.
- padding to show the background
- some extra bg-image(linear-gradient) to draw a fake button.
- tabindex to catch focus

```css
img {
  margin: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  padding: 100px 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(-35deg, transparent 50%, red 51%) no-repeat center 100px, linear-gradient(35deg, red 50%, transparent 51%) no-repeat center 80px, linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/people/9);
  background-size: 30px 20px, 30px 20px, auto, auto;
}

img:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(-35deg, transparent 50%, white 51%) no-repeat center 100px, linear-gradient(35deg, white 50%, transparent 51%) no-repeat center 80px, linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/people/9);
  background-size: 30px 20px, 30px 20px, auto, auto;
}

img:focus {
  background: linear-gradient(-35deg, transparent 100%, red 0%) no-repeat center 100px, linear-gradient(35deg, red 0%, transparent 0%) no-repeat center 80px, linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/people/9);
  background-size: 30px 20px, 30px 20px, auto, auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/city/9" alt="play" tabindex="0" />
```

to link to a video, you need a link ... :) CSS doesn't do this

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should do. Works OK on my end

```
<style>
.overlay {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}
</style>

<img src="overlay.png" class="overlay" width="128" height="128" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your images are in a separate container, you can play with the :after pseudo selector in css like this:

```css
#myimages li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

#myimages li:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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") left top no-repeat;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="myimages">
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city"></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

It's just a very plain example. In your situation the image's parent element could be an anchor tag pointing to the video url.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the image would be inside an `<a>` tag (since it links to videos), wouldn't it be useful for you to style the anchor tag as a block, then apply a play button style through `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements?

Check it out:

```
<style>
    .field {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .field:before {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        border-left: 50px solid red;
        border-top: 30px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .field:hover:before {
        border-left-color: blue;
    }
    .field:focus:before {
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
</style>
<a class="field">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="">
</a>
```

You can use a background image, or pretty much anything you can inside the pseudo element to illustrate your play button.
I hope this can be useful!